# How to increase the performance of Syncfusion ConvertToPDF method

Tags: pdf-generation, filestream, syncfusion, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

I use the following method to generate a PDF document using MS Word Mail merge. The “PaymentPlanDetails” has **7050** records and its data model has 9 *string* fields, an *int* field, a *decimal* field and a *DateTime* field.

```
private MemoryStream MergeOracleDisbursementToPdf(OracleDisbursementsHeader mailMergeModel, List<OracleDisbursementsDetailPDF> PaymentPlanDetails, byte[] fileBytes)
        {
            if (fileBytes == null || fileBytes.Length == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var templateStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
            var pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
            var wordStream = new MemoryStream();
            WordDocument mergeDocument = null;
            using (mergeDocument = new WordDocument(templateStream, FormatType.Docx))
            {
                if (mergeDocument != null)
                {
                    var mergeList = new List<OracleDisbursementsHeader> { mailMergeModel };
                    var reportDataSource = new MailMergeDataTable("Report", mergeList);
                    var tableDataSource = new MailMergeDataTable("PaymentPlanDetails", PaymentPlanDetails); 

                    List<DictionaryEntry> commands = new List<DictionaryEntry>();
                    commands.Add(new DictionaryEntry("Report", ""));
                    commands.Add(new DictionaryEntry("PaymentPlanDetails", ""));
                    MailMergeDataSet ds = new MailMergeDataSet();
                    ds.Add(reportDataSource);
                    ds.Add(tableDataSource);

                    mergeDocument.MailMerge.ExecuteNestedGroup(ds, commands);
                    mergeDocument.UpdateDocumentFields();                        
                    using (var converter = new DocIORenderer())
                    {
                        converter.Settings.
                        using (var pdfDocument = converter.ConvertToPDF(mergeDocument)) // takes 1 Min 15 Secs for 7050 Records
                        {
                            pdfDocument.Save(pdfStream);
                            pdfDocument.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    mergeDocument.Close();
                }
            }
            return pdfStream;
        }
```

The issue is the code hangs in the line of “`using (var pdfDocument = converter.ConvertToPDF(mergeDocument))`” for **1 Minute and 15 Seconds**. Is there a way to speed up this process?

**What I have tried so far:**

“https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/138495/conversion-of-large-word-doc-to-pdf-is-very-slow-also-often-results-in-out-of-memory-errors” article shows how to enable fast rendering. However, in the version that I am currently using, has no such member listed under “converter.Settings”.

Comment: I believe the slowness is coming from the actual PDF conversion part. What you need is more professional solutions made solely for such tasks. You are creating 7050 records but there are systems designed for millions of PDF document generation based on a template. There is one system I know of and it has Docker image that expects you to send your data to merge and it does the job for you. You just then get your PDF document out.

Comment: My organization has bought the Syncfusion Licences. It is the main reason that I try to stick into this approach. As this is a government organization, using another tool/library needs approval and it could be a long process. However, thank you for your advice. What you suggest is something that I must do at any cost if it would not be able to resolve this with Syncfusion itself.

Answer (score 1):

**EnableFastRendering member is not listed in "converter.settings":**
By default we have used Fast rendering approach in Portable platforms (Asp.Net Core and Xamarin) while performing Word to PDF conversion and so this "EnableFastRendering" property is not listed in these platforms. But we have provided this Fast rendering approach as an option in Base platforms (Windows Forms, WPF, Asp.Net Web Forms) while performing Word to PDF conversion and so it is listed in these above mentioned Base platforms.

**Suggestion to improve performance:**
We suggest you to use x64 processor to utilize the available RAM and reduce the execution time.

If you are still facing the same problem means, kindly provide us the following details from your end:

1. Input Word document with complete sample. If you have any confidential data in your Word document, please replace with some dummy data and provide us the same. We just need your document to recreate the problem you face.
2. Platform target used in your application. (Right click on your project -> Properties ->Build).
3. RAM used at your end.

Based on the above details, we will analyze further on the reported problem and will provide you the appropriate solution at the earliest.

**Note:** I work for Syncfusion